# ElasticSearch failed to find analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I configured my global custom analyzer in elasticsearch.yml,here is my configuration:

```
index :
analysis :
    analyzer :
        titleAnalyzer :
            type : custom
            tokenizer : ik_max_word
            filter : [titleSynoymFilter, englishStemmerFilter]
    filter :
        titleSynoymFilter :
            type : synonym
            synonyms_path : ../analysis/title_synonym.txt
        englishStemmerFilter :
            type : stemmer
            name : english
```

then I test my analyzer by running command `$ echo 'A drop in the ocean'| http :5600/_analyze?analyzer=titleAnalyzer`

but elasticsearch told me it failed to find the analyzer:

```
{
"error": {
    "reason": "failed to find analyzer [titleAnalyzer]",
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "reason": "[elastisearch][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]",
            "type": "remote_transport_exception"
        }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception"
},
"status": 400
}
```

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`? Also it seems you're missing the tokenizer definition above, can you add it?

Comment: I've tried your configuration above on ES 2.3.2 (after fixing some typos)  and it works fine for me and produces the expected tokens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you call `/_analyze` on the root path the analyzer is not found, try specifying at least one existing index on the path

```
$ echo 'A drop in the ocean'| http :5600/some_index/_analyze?analyzer=titleAnalyzer
                                              ^
                                              |
                                      add an index here
```

Comment: Very thanks for the help,Finally I solved it,however, i don't why there needs an index?